# Listing information about all database files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-management

Is it possible to list information about the files (MDF/LDF) of all databases on an SQL Server?

I'd like to get a list showing which database is using what files on the local disk.

What I tried:

- `exec sp_databases` all databases
- `select * from sys.databases` shows a lot of information about each database - but unfortunately it doesn't show the files used by each database.
- `select * from sys.database_files` shows the mdf/ldf files of the `master` database - but not the other databases

Comment: I've found that `select * from sys.database_files` works fine if you make sure to prefix it with a `use` statement pointing to the DB you are interested in. So: `use MyDb; select * from sys.database_files` works for me in SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use [sys.master_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx).

> Contains a row per file of a database as stored in the master
>   database. This is a single, system-wide view.

Comment: Thanks, that (joined with sys.databases) is what I was looking for!

Comment: select * from sys.master_files

Comment: @M4N If you just want to get the database name you can also call `DB_NAME(database_id)` instead joining with `sys.databases`

Answer (score 101):

If you want get location of Database you can check [Get All DBs Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057000/sql-server-get-all-database-with-mdf-and-ldf-file-location/27057140#27057140).
you can use `sys.master_files` for get location of db and `sys.database` to get db name

```
SELECT
    db.name AS DBName,
    type_desc AS FileType,
    Physical_Name AS Location
FROM
    sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN 
    sys.databases db ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
```

Answer (score 20):

I am using script to get empty space in each file:

```
Create Table ##temp
(
    DatabaseName sysname,
    Name sysname,
    physical_name nvarchar(500),
    size decimal (18,2),
    FreeSpace decimal (18,2)
)   
Exec sp_msforeachdb '
Use [?];
Insert Into ##temp (DatabaseName, Name, physical_name, Size, FreeSpace)
    Select DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName], Name,  physical_name,
    Cast(Cast(Round(cast(size as decimal) * 8.0/1024.0,2) as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar) Size,
    Cast(Cast(Round(cast(size as decimal) * 8.0/1024.0,2) as decimal(18,2)) -
        Cast(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8.0/1024.0 as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar) As FreeSpace
    From sys.database_files
'
Select * From ##temp
drop table ##temp
```

Size is expressed in KB.

Comment: What is `Use [?]` supposed to do? It gives an error that it cannot find that stored procedure. Removing it shows only multiple times the system databases.

Comment: Isn't size in MB?

Answer (score 6):

I've created this query:

```
SELECT 
    db.name AS                                   [Database Name], 
    mf.name AS                                   [Logical Name], 
    mf.type_desc AS                              [File Type], 
    mf.physical_name AS                          [Path], 
    CAST(
        (mf.Size * 8
        ) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(18, 1)) AS         [Initial Size (MB)], 
    'By '+IIF(
            mf.is_percent_growth = 1, CAST(mf.growth AS VARCHAR(10))+'%', CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(
        (mf.growth * 8
        ) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(18, 1)))+' MB') AS [Autogrowth], 
    IIF(mf.max_size = 0, 'No growth is allowed', IIF(mf.max_size = -1, 'Unlimited', CAST(
        (
                CAST(mf.max_size AS BIGINT) * 8
        ) / 1024 AS VARCHAR(30))+' MB')) AS      [MaximumSize]
FROM 
     sys.master_files AS mf
     INNER JOIN sys.databases AS db ON
            db.database_id = mf.database_id
```

Comment: thanks, just for those old versions not supporting IIF, just replace the 2 last columns calculation

Comment: 'By '+  CASE WHEN mf.is_percent_growth = 1 THEN CAST(mf.growth AS VARCHAR(10))+'%' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST((mf.growth * 8) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(18, 1))) +' MB' END AS [Autogrowth],
 CASE WHEN mf.max_size = 0 THEN  'No growth is allowed' ELSE 
  CASE WHEN mf.max_size = -1 THEN 'Unlimited' ELSE CAST((CAST(mf.max_size AS BIGINT) * 8 ) / 1024 AS VARCHAR(30))+' MB' END
 END as [MaximumSize]

Answer (score 4):

Executing following sql (It will only work when you don't have multiple mdf/ldf files for same database)

```
SELECT
    db.name AS DBName,
    (select mf.Physical_Name FROM sys.master_files mf where mf.type_desc = 'ROWS' and db.database_id = mf.database_id ) as DataFile,
    (select mf.Physical_Name FROM sys.master_files mf where mf.type_desc = 'LOG' and db.database_id = mf.database_id ) as LogFile
FROM sys.databases db
```

will return this output

```
DBName       DataFile                     LogFile
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master       C:\....\master.mdf           C:\....\mastlog.ldf
tempdb       C:\....\tempdb.mdf           C:\....\templog.ldf
model        C:\....\model.mdf            C:\....\modellog.ldf
```

and rest of the databases

If your TempDB's have multiple MDF's (like mine have), this script will fail.
However, you can use

```
WHERE db.database_id > 4
```

at the end and it will return all databases except system databases.

Comment: I realise it's a small dataset, but that's no reason to use correlated subqueries. They might be fine on Oracle but they are serious performance killers on SQL Server, because they cause row-by-row processing. Your script will query the sys.master_files table twice for every row in the sys.databases table.

Comment: In addition to Davos' comment... This script will also fail with errors if you have multiple datafiles or logfiles for any database. (e.g. Subquery returned more than 1 value.)

Comment: @Davos I know what you are saying but it depends how frequently you are executing this query otherwise it is pre-optimization which probably you don't need.

Comment: I generally agree that early optimization is bad, but what I am saying is that correlated subqueries are just a bad pattern that should never be used in the first place. There's always exceptions to 'never' rules, but this is not one of those cases. I know it's minor and it might really not matter here, but that's not the point. This is a public forum that newbies use to learn good practice, so you need to provide role model code.

Comment: The query will error if multiple data files are used in one of the databases. Here's a version of your query using joins instead. Cheers!

SELECT db.name AS DBName, db.database_id,
mfr.Physical_Name AS DataFile,
mfl.Physical_Name AS LogFile
FROM sys.databases db
JOIN sys.master_files mfr ON db.database_id=mfr.database_id AND mfr.type_desc='ROWS'
JOIN sys.master_files mfl ON db.database_id=mfl.database_id AND mfl.type_desc='LOG'
ORDER BY db.database_id

Comment: @Robert, I really appreciate your comment but would be better if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @adeel41, Thank you, you are very welcome. I thought there are already very good answers here and wasn't sure if my change warranted it's own answer. I will add it below. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this.

```
 select db_name(dbid) dbname, filename from sys.sysaltfiles
```

Answer (score 3):

Below script can be used to get following information:
 1. DB Size Info
 2. FileSpaceInfo
 3. AutoGrowth
 4. Recovery Model
 5. Log_reuse_backup information

```
CREATE TABLE #tempFileInformation
(
DBNAME          NVARCHAR(256),
[FILENAME]      NVARCHAR(256),
[TYPE]          NVARCHAR(120),
FILEGROUPNAME   NVARCHAR(120),
FILE_LOCATION   NVARCHAR(500),
FILESIZE_MB     DECIMAL(10,2),
USEDSPACE_MB    DECIMAL(10,2),
FREESPACE_MB    DECIMAL(10,2),
AUTOGROW_STATUS NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @SQL = '
 USE [?]
            INSERT INTO #tempFileInformation
            SELECT  
                DBNAME          =DB_NAME(),     
                [FILENAME]      =A.NAME,
                [TYPE]          = A.TYPE_DESC,
                FILEGROUPNAME   = fg.name,
                FILE_LOCATION   =a.PHYSICAL_NAME,
                FILESIZE_MB     = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0),
                USEDSPACE_MB    = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(A.SIZE/128.0 - ((A.SIZE - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME,''SPACEUSED'') AS INT))/128.0))),
                FREESPACE_MB    = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(A.SIZE/128.0 -  CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME,''SPACEUSED'') AS INT)/128.0)),
                AUTOGROW_STATUS = ''BY '' +CASE is_percent_growth when 0 then cast (growth/128 as varchar(10))+ '' MB - ''
                                                                  when 1 then cast (growth as varchar(10)) + ''% - '' ELSE '''' END
                                                                  + CASE MAX_SIZE WHEN 0 THEN '' DISABLED '' 
                                                                                  WHEN -1 THEN '' UNRESTRICTED''
                                                                                  ELSE '' RESTRICTED TO '' + CAST(MAX_SIZE/(128*1024) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '' GB '' END
                                                                + CASE IS_PERCENT_GROWTH WHEn 1 then '' [autogrowth by percent]'' else '''' end
    from sys.database_files A
    left join sys.filegroups fg on a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
    order by A.type desc,A.name
    ;
    '

    --print @sql

    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL
    go

    SELECT dbSize.*,fg.*,d.log_reuse_wait_desc,d.recovery_model_desc
    FROM #tempFileInformation fg
    LEFT JOIN sys.databases d on fg.DBNAME = d.name
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        select dbname,
                sum(FILESIZE_MB) as [totalDBSize_MB],
                sum(FREESPACE_MB) as [DB_Free_Space_Size_MB],
                sum(USEDSPACE_MB) as [DB_Used_Space_Size_MB]
            from #tempFileInformation
            where  dbname = fg.dbname
            group by dbname
    )dbSize


go
DROP TABLE #tempFileInformation
```

Answer (score 3):

Using this script you can show all the databases name and files used (with exception of system dbs).

```
select name,physical_name from sys.master_files where database_id > 4
```

Answer (score 2):

To get around queries which error when multiple data files (e.g. ".ndf" file types) exist, try this version, it replaces the sub-queries with joins.

Here's a version of your query using joins instead of the sub-queries.

Cheers!

```
SELECT
    db.name AS DBName,
    db.database_id,
    mfr.physical_name AS DataFile,
    mfl.physical_name AS LogFile
FROM sys.databases db
    JOIN sys.master_files mfr ON db.database_id=mfr.database_id AND mfr.type_desc='ROWS'
    JOIN sys.master_files mfl ON db.database_id=mfl.database_id AND mfl.type_desc='LOG'
ORDER BY db.database_id
```

Sample Results:
(Please note, the single log file is paired with each MDF and NDF for a single database)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this SQL query for retrieving files list :

```
SELECT d.name AS DatabaseName, 
       m.name AS LogicalName, 
       m.physical_name AS PhysicalName, 
       size AS FileSize
FROM sys.master_files m
     INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON(m.database_id = d.database_id)
     where d.name = '<Database Name>'
ORDER BY physical_name ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This script lists most of what you are looking for and can hopefully be modified to you needs. Note that it is creating a permanent table in there - you might want to change it. It is a subset from a larger script that also summarises backup and job information on various servers.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DriveInfo') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #DriveInfo
CREATE TABLE #DriveInfo
 (
    Drive CHAR(1)
    ,MBFree INT
 ) 

INSERT  INTO #DriveInfo
      EXEC master..xp_fixeddrives


IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Tmp_tblDatabaseInfo]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[Tmp_tblDatabaseInfo]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tmp_tblDatabaseInfo](
      [ServerName] [nvarchar](128) NULL
      ,[DBName] [nvarchar](128)  NULL
      ,[database_id] [int] NULL
      ,[create_date] datetime NULL
      ,[CompatibilityLevel] [int] NULL
      ,[collation_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL
      ,[state_desc] [nvarchar](60) NULL
      ,[recovery_model_desc] [nvarchar](60) NULL
      ,[DataFileLocations] [nvarchar](4000)
      ,[DataFilesMB] money null
      ,DataVolumeFreeSpaceMB INT NULL
      ,[LogFileLocations] [nvarchar](4000)
      ,[LogFilesMB] money null
      ,LogVolumeFreeSpaceMB INT NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tmp_tblDatabaseInfo] 
SELECT 
      @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName] 
      ,d.name AS DBName 
      ,d.database_id
      ,d.create_date
      ,d.compatibility_level  
      ,CAST(d.collation_name AS [nvarchar](128)) AS collation_name
      ,d.[state_desc]
      ,d.recovery_model_desc
      ,(select physical_name + ' | ' AS [text()]
         from sys.master_files m
         WHERE m.type = 0 and m.database_id = d.database_id
         ORDER BY file_id
         FOR XML PATH ('')) AS DataFileLocations
      ,(select sum(size) from sys.master_files m WHERE m.type = 0 and m.database_id = d.database_id)  AS DataFilesMB
      ,NULL
      ,(select physical_name + ' | ' AS [text()]
         from sys.master_files m
         WHERE m.type = 1 and m.database_id = d.database_id
         ORDER BY file_id
         FOR XML PATH ('')) AS LogFileLocations
      ,(select sum(size) from sys.master_files m WHERE m.type = 1 and m.database_id = d.database_id)  AS LogFilesMB
      ,NULL
FROM  sys.databases d  

WHERE d.database_id > 4 --Exclude basic system databases
UPDATE [dbo].[Tmp_tblDatabaseInfo] 
   SET DataFileLocations = 
      CASE WHEN LEN(DataFileLocations) > 4 THEN  LEFT(DataFileLocations,LEN(DataFileLocations)-2) ELSE NULL END
   ,LogFileLocations =
      CASE WHEN LEN(LogFileLocations) > 4 THEN  LEFT(LogFileLocations,LEN(LogFileLocations)-2) ELSE NULL END
   ,DataFilesMB = 
      CASE WHEN DataFilesMB > 0 THEN  DataFilesMB * 8 / 1024.0   ELSE NULL END
   ,LogFilesMB = 
      CASE WHEN LogFilesMB > 0 THEN  LogFilesMB * 8 / 1024.0  ELSE NULL END
   ,DataVolumeFreeSpaceMB = 
      (SELECT MBFree FROM #DriveInfo WHERE Drive = LEFT( DataFileLocations,1))
   ,LogVolumeFreeSpaceMB = 
      (SELECT MBFree FROM #DriveInfo WHERE Drive = LEFT( LogFileLocations,1))

select * from [dbo].[Tmp_tblDatabaseInfo]
```

Comment: An excellent script that can be copy/pasted and used as-is. One question though, I see that for `LogVolumeFreeSpaceMB` it always shows the same amount for all files, in my case 44756. Is it possible to get the actual free space? Or is that the number of max free space on the drive where the LDF is located?

Comment: Hi Abel - It has been a while since I wrote and I am not really sure of your issue. There is an alternative to XP_FIXEDDRIVES called sys.dm_os_volume_stats so you can try using that. If the problem is that the file sizes of the database are not changing over time then that is normal as SQL Server allocates a big blob of empty disk space for its use and then doesn't expand that file until it has been filled up. It will expand a file in jumps with the amount determined by the file settings for that particular database

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your Database, MS SQL Server does not rename the underlying files.

Following query gives you the current name of the database and the Logical file name (which might be the original name of the Database when it was created) and also corresponding physical file names.

Note: Un-comment the last line to see only the actual data files

```
select  db.database_id, 
        db.name "Database Name", 
        files.name "Logical File Name",
        files.physical_name
from    sys.master_files files 
        join sys.databases db on db.database_id = files.database_id 
--                           and files.type_desc = 'ROWS'
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Using the sp_MSForEachDB stored procedure is an option

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'use ? select * from sys.database_files'
```

Additionally to see just the Full Path name and size information

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB '
USE [?];
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
    physical_name AS FullPath,
    name AS FileName, 
    type_desc,
    size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB,  
    size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type IN (0,1);
'
```

Answer (score 0):

just adding my 2 cents .

if specifically looking to find total free space only in Data files or only in Log files  in all the databases, we can use "data_space_id" column. 1 is for data files and 0 for log files.

CODE:

```
Create Table ##temp
(
    DatabaseName sysname,
    Name sysname,
    spacetype sysname,
    physical_name nvarchar(500),
    size decimal (18,2),
    FreeSpace decimal (18,2)
)   
Exec sp_msforeachdb '
Use [?];

Insert Into ##temp (DatabaseName, Name,spacetype, physical_name, Size, FreeSpace)
    Select DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName], Name,   ***data_space_id*** , physical_name,
    Cast(Cast(Round(cast(size as decimal) * 8.0/1024.0,2) as decimal(18,2))/1024 as nvarchar) SizeGB,
    Cast(Cast(Round(cast(size as decimal) * 8.0/1024.0,2)/1024 as decimal(18,2)) -
        Cast(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8.0/1024.0 as decimal(18,2))/1024 as nvarchar) As FreeSpaceGB
    From sys.database_files'


select  
    databasename
    , sum(##temp.FreeSpace) 
from 
    ##temp 
where 
    ##temp.spacetype = 1  
group by 
    DatabaseName

drop table ##temp
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the below:

```
SP_HELPDB [Master]
GO
```

Comment: This only provides info for the single specified database.  The question is for ALL databases.