# SQL Server - get all databases with MDF and LDF File Location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a T-SQL query for a list of all databases in SQL Server 2008 showing

- the name of the database and
- the location of the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

Comment: Please use the table, sys.database_files

Comment: @MehdiHaghshenas If you spend 2 minutes on Google, `mssql get all databases and locations` returned 26 million results.

Comment: ironically, this question is now the third result when googling the exact search phrase suggested above

Comment: Voting to reopen. It does not matter how much effort the OP put in it; it's now a high-ranking result on Google and apparently helps a lot of people.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
SELECT
    db.name AS DBName,
    type_desc AS FileType,
    Physical_Name AS Location
FROM
    sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN 
    sys.databases db ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of joining to databases table, you can `SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DBName`

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
select 
    d.name as 'database',
    mdf.physical_name as 'mdf_file',
    ldf.physical_name as 'log_file'
from sys.databases d
inner join sys.master_files mdf on 
    d.database_id = mdf.database_id and mdf.[type] = 0
inner join sys.master_files ldf on 
    d.database_id = ldf.database_id and ldf.[type] = 1
```

Comment: I don't like this solution because it gets complicated if there are many mdf/log files per database.

Answer (score -4):

Try this query:

```
SELECT name [Database Name], physical_name [File Location],size *(8.0 / 1024) /1024 [Size in GBs]
FROM sys.master_files
```

Comment: While this answers the question, this is basically a repeat of other answers. In this case the proper way to go about this is upvote other answers (once you have sufficient reputation), not repeat another answer.