# Get DBs Location In A Network Server by a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a query in T-SQL that pulls out the location of all databases within a server in the network (not the local drive).

I had a look at this example [SQL Server - get all databases with MDF and LDF File Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057000/sql-server-get-all-databases-with-mdf-and-ldf-file-location/27057140#27057140) 
.But, it didn't seem to work, I am guessing this is due to the location of this server which is not local.

Comment: the answer in your linked question is the best you can get since SQL server only "knows" the file location in its own environment you can see the same info looking at the `properties/files` menu of each DB

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - get all databases with MDF and LDF File Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057000/sql-server-get-all-databases-with-mdf-and-ldf-file-location)

Comment: No it clearly is not Farheg. Read it before commenting

Comment: My understanding of the your statement 'didn't seem to work'...didn't seem to work. What were you expecting and what did you get?

Comment: Nothing happened, it produced a blank table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked answer works but you must have enough permissions to view the results.

From [sys.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx):

> If the caller of **sys.databases** is not the owner of the database and the database is not **master** or **tempdb**, the minimum permissions required to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY DATABASE or VIEW ANY DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE DATABASE permission in the **master** database. The database to which the caller is connected can always be viewed in **sys.databases**.

From [sys.master_files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx):

> The minimum permissions that are required to see the corresponding row are CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION.