# Return Database Name from sys.database_files

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how the Database Name can be returned? I can't seem to figure out how to join `sys.database_files` to `sys.databases`.

```
SELECT
    a.NAME as FileName,
    FG.name as FileGroup,
    a.physical_name as FilePath,
    a.type_desc as FileType,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(a.size/128.000,2)) AS [Size],
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)) AS [Used] ,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND((a.size-FILEPROPERTY(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) AS [Free]
FROM 
    sys.database_files a
LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups FG ON 
    FG.data_space_id = a.data_space_id
```

Comment: this seems helpfull:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630279/listing-information-about-all-database-files-in-sql-server

Comment: `sys.database_files` returns files from the current database - not all databases. So `select db_name()` unless you are calling it with a three part name...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sys.master_files` instead - that has `database_id` - like this:

```
select 
    a.NAME as FileName,
    FG.name as FileGroup,
    a.physical_name as FilePath,
    a.type_desc as FileType,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(a.size/128.000,2)) AS [Size],
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)) AS [Used] ,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND((a.size-FILEPROPERTY(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) AS [Free]
from sys.master_files a
LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups FG ON 
    FG.data_space_id = a.data_space_id;
```

**Edit :**
To add database name to the query:

```
select 
    d.name as DatabaseName,
    a.name as FileName,
    FG.name as FileGroup,
    a.physical_name as FilePath,
    a.type_desc as FileType,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(a.size/128.000,2)) AS [Size],
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)) AS [Used] ,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND((a.size-FILEPROPERTY(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) AS [Free]
from sys.databases d
left join sys.master_files a on d.database_id = a.database_id
left join sys.filegroups FG on
    FG.data_space_id = a.data_space_id;
```

Comment: The user was asking how to get the database name.  Your "solution" doesn't contain the database name...

Comment: @DavidWilson Good point, thanks, I forgot to add a sample with database name ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.NAME as FileName ,b.name as FileGroup , b.physical_name as FilePath,   b.type_desc as FileType,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(b.size/128.000,2)) AS [Size],
CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(b.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)) AS [Used] ,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),ROUND((b.size-FILEPROPERTY(b.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) AS [Free]
FROM Sys.databases a 
INNER JOIN  Sys.master_files b ON a.database_id=b.database_id
WHERE a.database_id >4
```